# Database files restored from postgresql 13 are incompatible with server having postgresql 15

Tags: postgresql

I have restored the database from backup  of the server that was having postgresql 13.3 to postgresql 15 however the postgresql 15 failed to start. I have used pgbackrest to backup and restoration
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1).
Please help

Comment: Without details of what you did this cannot be answered.

Comment: I have used the pgbackrest to backup the postgesql 13 database, then I have restored in postgreql 15 successfully but the database failed to start

Comment: 1) That is still not enough information. The exact commands you used are needed. 2) You can't restore to different Postgres version. pgBackRest  works on the cluster level and you will need to restore to the same version data directory.

Comment: If you want to change versions you will need to either  1) Do [dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) or 2) [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html).  Since you seem to be on Debian you should look to see if `pg_upgradecluster` is installed and if so do `man pg_upgradecluster` to see how to run it. It is a wrapper around `pg_upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

A data directory in the format for v13 needs to be run by software version v13.  Install the v13 server software and run it.

You could upgrade the database data directory from v13 to v15, but doing that will still include getting a runnable v13 installation as a necessary step.